# Timecode questions

Tags: timecode

So I'm transferring and EDL and heres the situation.  The timecode on the EDL doesn't match with the time code on my Pro Tools Session
--clarification
The third number pair xx:xx:33:xx goes up higher than my pro tools session goes.  Pro Tools session goes up to 23 and this goes up at least to 42 and thats just by judging the first page of the EDL.
Whats the deal here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, being timecode is HH:MM:SS:FF, you're talking about the seconds, in which case it should go up to 59 and then roll over to 00, so any number from 00-59 is valid, regardless of your framerate.  So if 23 seconds is as far as PT is going, I'd say PT is likely what's in the wrong here.

If you incorrectly listed that and meant frames instead of seconds, than likely you were provided an EDL that's in an HD/ATSC standard which supports 60 and 59.94 (NDF and DF flavors) - both of which are simply double the normal NTSC framerates (30 and 29.97, respectively).  In PT if you enable Timecode 2, these become visible options.

To tell if it's NDF or DF, it usually has a **;** between the SS and FF.  **The other way to tell is that in DF, the first 2 frame numbers of each round Minute are dropped except on the 10s (the round 10-minute values)**.  That one's saved me lots of times when the colon/semicolon paradigm was carelessly forgotten on a BITC and had to figure out what timecode they're in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Stavro.  Its been awhile since I learned the proper linguistics of timecode and I much forgot.  haha.

Also, what threw me off was that the original OMF started at the 07 hour.  The new timecode started at a normal hour.  After I figured that out it all fell into place.

Right now I'm demoing Titan to conform on PT9 but I've had no luck yet....
What does it mean when it says in bold letters after you flashcut, AUDIO NOT FOUND and how do you fix it?